# Compiling gRPC on MacOS for Darwin ARM64 - using bazel or cmake instead of make

Tags: makefile, cmake, compilation, bazel

OS: MacOS 11
Platform: Apple M1 architecture (Darwin ARM64)

According to

https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/github.com/grpc/grpc/+/HEAD/BUILDING.md

using `make` is outdated.

I downloaded and installed bazel Darwin x64 (MacOS Intel) binary latest version, `bazel build :all` completed without errors.

`bazel test --config=dbg //test/...` however prints out a lot of errors after a few minutes of compiling.

There's also the option to run cmake, which also completes.

So, my question is, am I correct if `cmake` or `bazel` (with `build :all`, of course) does not install the binaries, but rather `make` and `(sudo) make install` do?

If the use of `make` is "outdated", is bazel / cmake used to install the compiled binaries?